# How to add multiple "AND" conditions in a JOIN

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

I'm trying to add a "AND" condition to the join query but haven't been able to figure it out (not sure if it's even possible via Doctrine/Symfony). I'd appreciate any help with this.

```
->select('c, p')
->from(Customer::class, 'c')
->leftJoin('c.phones', 'p')
```

Example:-

```
SELECT c.*, p.*
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN phone p ON c.id = p.customer_id AND p.is_main = 1 AND p.category = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditionType of the leftJoin function in queryBuilder [check the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)

```
    public function leftJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);

    Example:
    $qb->leftJoin('c.phones', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.is_main = 1 AND p.category = 0', 'p.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WITH option like this:

```
$qb->leftJoin('c.phones', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.is_main = 1 AND p.category = 0', 'p.id')
```

[Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder)